# How do document service responses in ServiceStack with Servicestack swagger-api (1.2)

Tags: c#, rest, servicestack, swagger

I am using [swagger ui](http://docs.servicestack.net/swagger-api%22swagger-api%22) for the documentation of my ServiceStack web-services which works quite nice. However I did not find a way to add any information about the responses of those web-services (json). So when the `GET` method of my service looks like this:

```
    public object Get(CustomerData customers)
    {
         List<CustomerDAO> customers = DataProvider.GetAllCustomers();
         return customers;
    }


 public class CustomerDAO
 {
     // this is important information which needs to be visible in swagger-ui
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string SomeImportantProperty { get; set; }    
    public string AnotherPropery { get; set; }
    public string AlsoWorthDocumenting { get; set; }
    // and so on...
  }
```

I need a short description of each property in the documentation (swagger-ui) which is essential for using those web-services.

I am using ServiceStack 3.9.74 but this should also apply to the latest ServiceStack version. If not please let me know.

I was wondering how I can get this information in swagger, or if not, how to supply such important information to the developers who have to work with my web services. I am also open for any other approaches or best practices which will work in the environment of ServiceStack.

Comment: @stout01's answer is correct, also highly recommend following advice to always create a dedicated response object for your services. Even better, try not to expose types used by your ORM (OrmLite?) as it creates a tight coupling between your data access and your API which is now exposed to your API's clients. This it makes it very hard for you to change your database model without breaking your API contract and your clients. Another type that represents a `Customer` should be created as well.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure about your version of ServiceStack.  In the latest version you would have your request dto inheirt `IReturn<ReturnClassHere>` which would tell swagger to look at that return class.

So your CustomerData class would look something like this:

```
public class CustomerData : IReturn<List<CustomerDAO>>
{
}
```

Although it would probably be better to setup another dto for your response that would be returned instead. Maybe something like `CustomerDataResponse`.

Comment: Unfortunately that does not work in 1.2. I also added `ApiMember` Attribute to the properties of the response, but swagger does not pick it up. I guess this feature is not part of 1.2.